# Yii: deleteAll and IN statement

Tags: yii

I have array with ids and want to delete all them by id

```
$membersId = array('1','2','3');
$inStatement = implode(',', $membersId);

//dont work!
TRatingMembers::model()->deleteAll(array('member_id IN (:member_id)'),
    array(':member_id' => $inStatement));
```

How to delete all rows with one transaction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition('member_id',$membersId);
TRatingMembers::model()->deleteAll($criteria);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!empty(membersId)) {
    $memberIds = implode(', ', $membersId);
    TRatingMembers::model()->deleteAll('member_id IN (' . $memberIds . ')');
}
```

Comment: Is it safe? SQL-Injection?!

Comment: It's safe if your array contains valid values.

Comment: I got it. You can also consider this: `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->delete('video', array('IN', 'id', $extraIds));`